# How to make python logging persistent with docker

Tags: python, docker, logging, docker-compose

I am running a `python` application as a `docker` container and in my `python` application I am using pythons `logging` class to log execution steps using `logger.info`, `logger.debug` and `logger.error`. The problem with this is the log file is only persistent within the `docker` container and if the container goes away then the log file is also lost and also that every time I have to view the log file I have to manually copy the container log file to local system.What I want to do is that whatever log is being written to container log file, it should be persistent on the local system - so write to a local system log file or Auto mount the docker log file to local system.

Few things about my host machine:

1. I run multiple docker containers on the machine.
2. My sample docker-core file is:

   `FROM server-base-v1
   ADD . /app
   WORKDIR /app
   ENV PATH /app:$PATH
   CMD ["python","-u","app.py"]`
3. My sample docker-base file is:

   `FROM python:3
   ADD ./setup /app/setup
   WORKDIR /app
   RUN pip install -r setup/requirements.txt`
4. A sample of my docker-compose.yml file is:

`

```
version: "2"
networks:
    server-net:

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongodb
    hostname: mongodb
    networks:
      - server-net
    volumes:
      - /dockerdata/mongodb:/data/db

    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
        - "28017:28017"

  server-core-v1:
    container_name: server-core-v1
    image: server-core-v1:latest
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
            - server-net
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
        - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

`

Above yml file sample is just a part of my actual yml file. I have multiple `server-core-v1` containers(with different names) running parallel with each having their own logging  file.

I would also appreciate if there are some better strategies for doing logging in python with docker and make it persistent. I read few articles which mentioned using `sys.stderr.write()` and `sys.stdout.write()` but not sure how to use that especially with multiple containers running and logging.

Comment: Attach a volume to the container. Store the log files in the volume. Even if the container gets deleted, you still have the log files in the volume

Answer (score 2):

**Bind-mounts** are what you need.

[image]

As you can see, bind-mounts are accesible from yours host file system. It is very simmilar to shared folders in VM architecture.
You can simple achieve that with mounting your volume directly to path on your PC.
In yours case:

```
version: "2"
networks:
    server-net:

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongodb
    hostname: mongodb
    networks:
      - server-net
    volumes:
      - /dockerdata/mongodb:/data/db

    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
        - "28017:28017"

  server-core-v1:
    container_name: server-core-v1
    image: server-core-v1:latest
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
            - server-net
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
        - ./yours/example/host/path:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Just replace `./yours/example/host/path` with target directory on yours host.
In this scenario, i belive that logger is on server side.

If you are working on windows remember to bind in current user directory!

Answer (score 1):

**Volumes** are what you need.

You can create volumes to bind an internal container folder with a local system folder. So that you can store your logs in a `logs` folder and map this as a volume to any folder on your local system.

You can specify a volume in the docker-compose.yml file for each service you are creating. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).